# Plugin configuration in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I'm investigating the use of Eclipse as a platform and I am trying to figure out how a plugin provides configuration. For example, say I have a plugin to display a user defined message. Further, I want that user defined message to be configured by the user. What is the standard way for the user to edit this message in the platform? Is there any documentation for this?

Comment: Found it: http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Preferences/preferences.htm

Wow, Stackoverflow helps a lot! You only need to post and it magically comes up in Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it: http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Preferences/preferences.htm Wow, Stackoverflow helps a lot! You only need to post and it magically comes up in Google

Sorry to VonC but I had already found it before he posted the answer :-/

Comment: @cheez: no problem ;) I just wanted to illustrate your comment and make it more visible. The answer tick is rightfully yours.

Answer (score 3):

As you mentions in the comments, the article **[Preferences in the Eclipse Workbench UI](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Preferences/preferences.htm)** described the way developers define preference pages for their plug-ins.

> By use of the preference store in conjunction with the preferences dialog and provided field editors a plug-in developer can quickly put together a user interface for managing preferences.
>   The color preference page is an example of a simple page that uses a single JFace field editor to manage its values

That way, you can define several type of custom values configured by the user:

- text field
- set of predefined values (dropdown list)
- array of values

Example:

[image: Secure Storage]